# Google Cloud - BiqQuery, Invalid schema update. Field has changed type from INTEGER to STRING

Tags: python, google-bigquery, dataset, config, gcloud

In GCP, using python, my `query` selects some data to be inserted in table `BQ_table`.

`query` produces 2 fileds/columns: A String and Integer.

`BQ_table` follows `schema`.

```
    schema = [  bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
                bigquery.SchemaField("age", "INTEGER", mode="NULLABLE") 
          ]
    config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination= BQ_table,  autodetect=True, schema=schema)
    query_job = self._client.query(query, job_config=config)
    que
```

My questions is how can I list/show all possible **Datasets** and **Tables** in my current project?
I could not find the proper `gcloud` | `gsutil` command.

The Data can be inserted, type of `age` from `STRING` to `INTEGER`, but I'm wondering what am I missing to insert the numeric data into the table.

The **error** is:

> Google Cloud - BiqQuery, Invalid schema update. Field  has changed
> type from INTEGER to STRING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of all datasets in Google BigQuery can be queried from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-datasets):

```
SELECT * FROM region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```

List of tables in Google BigQuery can be queried from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables):

```
-- Returns metadata for tables in a single dataset.
SELECT * FROM myDataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

-- Returns metadata for tables in a region.
SELECT * FROM region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

To insert STRING to INTEGER try to explicitly convert it in query with [CAST or SAFE_CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting) first:

```
SELECT CAST("123" AS INT64);
SELECT SAFE_CAST("apple" AS INT64);
```