# Value has changed type from string to Integer BQ error

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a value id that I get from my users and I set it as a string because the value can be alphanumeric. But when I get a user with an all numeric id value, I get the above error.

Is "string" not a more generic data type? Curious what I can set it to, so it can cover all scenarios.

Comment: Can you add more details.  What do you mean by "I have a value id that I get from my users".  What statement/command are you running that results in the error?

Comment: Hi Spider, I have posted an answer If it addresses your issue you can consider accepting and upvoting else please provide additional information by replying to the comment posted by @Kolban.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] as per this page; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error commonly occurs when a BigQuery table column expects value as a string but receives value as an integer. String data types commonly handle both string and numeric data types in most of the DBMS and programming languages. According to this official [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types), it seems like in BigQuery there is no generic data type.

When you are inserting different data type values into the BigQuery table you can consider using BigQuery built-in functions like `CAST` or `SAFE_CAST` to convert into the expected data type format. If you are using any programming libraries then before inserting, convert values into the expected datatype format. You can easily achieve this by using some data type conservation method inside the condition statement.

For more information refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#cast) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64743099/).

Comment: Hi Kiran, I think this might be right, however I send the data into google pubsub and in pubsub I have a subscription to bigquery.

If i send integer or float data in place of a string, will there be an issue?

Comment: Hi @Spider , when I tried to insert int64 value into the table using sql query I got the following error message ‘Value has type INT64 which cannot be inserted into column data, which has type STRING’. When a message is published using PubSub in the following format {‘column_name’:’87.9’} it is successfully inserted into the table. So it is better to use the correct data type.